# Is it okay to typeset someone’s to-be-graded assignment for them?

Tags: ethics, plagiarism, formatting, cheating

I have a friend who’s an undergraduate at university. I believe myself to be fairly proficient in TeX/LaTeX; I’ve seen some of the assignments that he’s received back, and we both agree they could look more professional.

Is it ethical for me to typeset his work to look more like a paper before it's submitted for grading? I would not be adding any new information to the assignment and I would not correct any mistakes that I think I see, but it still seems to me that perhaps it could be against the rules.

Comment: You say the assignment has already been graded?  Is it going to be handed back in for regrading, or submitted for some other academic purpose?  If not, I don't see how there could possibly be any problem.

Comment: No, I mean the assignment is to be graded (it will directly impact his grade).

Comment: I would have them ask the instructor if its ok, he is the ultimate authority in this case.  If this was a class on how to use LaTeX its clearly not ok.  However, in other cases it might be ok.

Comment: If it affects his grade, it is clearly a violation

Comment: Back in the old days (pre-ominipresent computers, my experience is early 1980's) a fair number of students made good money typing other people's essays (the alternative was handing in a hand-written essay or typing it slowly oneself if you weren't a good typist). And there were a good number of people in the community who advertised as well. If you are not editing as you go, I really do not see the problem. If the professor is swayed by how it looks, that is a different problem.

Comment: You're so innocent! How would you typeset [**this**](https://media.boingboing.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Screen-Shot-2012-05-24-at-10.54.16-AM.jpg)? :-) (exaggerating obviously, but hopefully you can see the point underneath)

Comment: Different idea: write a pandoc latex template for your friend and teach him how to use markdown + pandoc.  Won't cover all cases where latex code is necessary, but hopefully most.

Comment: There was a very good student in my department, a couple years ahead of me, who had trouble with handwriting growing up.  He coped by training himself to write big.  His submissions were twice as many pages as the average, because he wrote so big. It takes practice to write that big! Alternatively, it would be a big asset for your friend if he knew how to use math word processing or typesetting or speech to text software.  You could teach him.

Comment: Tell your friend to buy a copy of Grind EQ if his professor objects.  Back in the day (as Jon Custer mentioned) these services were widely used and advertised.

Comment: Back when dinosaurs roamed the Earth it was commonplace to employ a typist for theses and papers. I don't see any problem with simply typesetting an assignment.

Comment: "Student... look professional." This is a category error.

Comment: Show him how. It's obviously something he could stand to learn.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/81082/should-formatting-affect-grades-of-student-essays

Comment: Publishing? Absolutely! Classwork? Where are your priorities for what matters in the world?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I think this is probably not appropriate.  You could ask the professor, but if it were me I would say no.

An important part of learning math at the undergraduate level is being able to write math clearly, and this includes the low-level yet essential skill of being able to handwrite or typeset math notation.  If you're typesetting the assignments for your friend, the professor is not getting an accurate view of their proficiency at this skill, which could factor into the grade.

There could be an exception if your friend has a disability that makes it unusually difficult for him to write clearly by hand.  But again, you would need the consent of the professor (and possibly also of some university disability service office).

(If your friend doesn't have a disability but just has particularly atrocious handwriting, the professor might agree to this, simply out of self-preservation; reading bad handwriting can be really frustrating.)

I agree with Massimo Ortolano that in the long run, the best thing would be to help your friend learn to typeset the assignments himself.  You could of course typeset some of his *previous* assignments for him as an example.

Comment: i was *once* asked to submit a handwritten math assignment.from that teacher's point of view, atrocious is an underreaction.

Comment: Furthermore even if the person doing the typesetting honestly intends it to be "just typesetting" it is difficult to rule out them either adding (because they made a typo) tor removing (because their brain read what it thought should be there rather than what was actually there) errors.

Answer (score 92):

I think that the best favour you can do to your friend is to teach him how to use LaTeX, so that he can improve the look of his work by himself.

In this way, you won't go against any rule and you'll teach your friend a new skill.

Comment: Excellent advice, which otherwise doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Rather than teaching LaTeX, you could suggest LyX (or similar), which is easier. (Whether it is worth learning LaTeX depends on a person's career plan.)

Comment: @Orion - from the help center: _What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful_

Comment: @Kimball I personally like and _encourage_ such useful "alternative" answers. I simple noted that _it doesn't answer the question about whether x is ethical_.

Answer (score 8):

In my department, any homework/assignment etc. ends with a declaration which includes the claim that the author(s) did all of the work themselves unless mentioned otherwise.

My opinion is that typesetting is a process that is included in the assignment and while not explicitly stated is work you should do yourself.

I do agree with Massimo Ortolano that showing someone the ropes with a typesetting system is a good way to handle the situation though.

Comment: I did not notice this answer until I saw there was a Low Quality Post flag raised against it. After I read the answer, I decided to give it an upvote because it's a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with a lot of the other answers and comments: I think ultimately it should be the professor who makes this decision.

That said, I've occasionally had students ask me if it was acceptable to do similar things. Many times – assuming I didn't feel it was a matter of academic integrity – I've answered by saying it would be okay if the student got formatting help, but I wanted them to **acknowledge the help openly in the assignment**.

In other words, an assignment such as the one you are describing could include footnote with an acknowledgement, something to the effect of:

> <sub>This assignment was typeset in LaTeX by J. Smith</sub>

That way, everything is above board, and the student isn't passing off someone else's work as their own.

One other idea that might be considered or proposed is handing in a copy of original work along with the LaTeX document, so the professor can get an idea of what the original work looked like before the improvements.

Answer (score 5):

How much the look of the assignment/paper affects the result?

If the key value is the content (proof, research results, etc.) and the look is just the icing on a cake I dare to say your help is acceptable. At least your friend realized that the outcome he produced can be improved and you showed them how it can be improved.

If the graphic outcome is the key value, your friend's topic is graphics, for example, then your help - typesetting it for them - is unethical. Teaching them to use (XxLa)TeX is, on the other hand, completely different case.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, back when dinosaurs roamed the earth, students (and others) routinely hired typists to type their papers. There was nothing wrong with this then, and there's nothing wrong with it now, although I haven't heard of anyone hiring a typist in decades (except in the case of disability).

LaTeX, unfortunately, tends to occupy a different place in many professors' minds than typing does. In principle, having someone else TeX your work is no different from hiring a typist, and in fact in the early days of TeX the only people using it were professional technical typists. However, many professors, especially in mathematics, believe that "learning TeX" is an integral part of the course if they specify that assignments need to be LaTeXed. So it is probably not acceptable to typeset your friend's assignment if the professor requires LaTeX.

Comment: I just think the OP will have trouble copying the document without also doing some formatting...especially since they say that the students work looks unprofessional, and they want to make it look more professional.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to do this work for him?

Is it because he is your friend and you want to help him?  Why don't you help him *learn* LaTeX then instead of doing all the work of typesetting yourself? ([Give a man a fish...](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)) You can help him learn by guiding him through typesetting a non-graded homework assignment.

Is it because you believe that he is likely to get a better grade if the typesetting is better?  If *your* work directly influences *his* grade, the answer is clear: it's inappropriate. He should be graded solely on his own work.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience in the UK, both the Undergraduate course (completed in 2013) and my current Masters programme have had various stipulations on submission presentation.

I can recall a particular assignment in the final year of my undergraduate degree where the marking scheme required submission in IEEE format with appropriate referencing. It was constructed such that if you followed the format and referenced correctly you would attain 30% of the marks, regardless of content.

The module leader allowed us to peer review the submissions as it was his (rather clever) way of teaching us to critique. You would be amazed how many failed to read the marking scheme and didn't submit in a format that you [can download from the internet](https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html).

Your friend needs to learn that in the real world presentation, together with spelling and grammar are often as important as said content. If you can proficiently enable him and have the time and patience, he can go away and do it for a lifetime.